# Chords of a circle

Tags: geometry

Let AC and BD be two chords of a circle with center O such that they intersect at right angles
inside the circle at the point M. Suppose K and L are the mid-points of the chord AB and
CD respectively. Prove that OKML is a parallelogram.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas on where to start? Do you know how the figure should look like?

Comment: yeah,I can draw the figure

Comment: It seems like if you could show $OK \perp AC$ and $OL \perp BD$ it would help.

Comment: I think its actually a rectangle.

Comment: see the 5th statement in this link http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Circles/The-chords-in-a-circle-and-the-radii-perpendicular-to-the-chords.lesson

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First of all, $OK,OL$ are perpendicular bisectors (I hope you can prove that).

$\triangle AMB$ is a right triangle and $MK$ is the  median which corresponds to hypotenuse $AB \implies KM=\dfrac {AB} 2$ (this is derived by a theorem).

For a similar reason, in the right $\triangle CMD$, it is true that $ML=\dfrac {CD} 2 $.

$\angle KBM =x = \angle KMB$, due to $\triangle KMB $ is isosceles.

However, $\angle ABM= x= \angle ACD$, (as inscribed angles, which correspond to the same arc).

That means that $\angle LMC =x = \angle LCM$, due to $\triangle LMC $ is isosceles.

Taking as a fact that the sum of the angles in every triangle is $180^\circ$, we can prove that the red angles are $90^\circ-2x$, working on triangles $\triangle KMB $ and $\triangle MLC$.

It is obvious that $\angle KML=90^\circ +2x $. Moreover, due to the fact that $KOLM$ is quadrilateral$\implies$ the sum of its angles is equal to $360^\circ$, so we can prove that $\angle KOL=90^\circ+2x$, as well.

Finally, in quadrilateral $KOLM$ we have 2 pairs of congruent opposite angles$\implies KOLM $ is  a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the midpoint of the hypotenuse of a right triangle is the center of the triangle's circumcircle; therefore, $\overline{KA} \cong \overline{KB} \cong \overline{KX}$. Also, inscribed angles subtending the same arc of a circle are congruent, so that 
$\angle B \cong \angle C$.

[image]

Now, follow the angle chase to see that $\angle 1 \cong \angle 5$, and therefore that $\overline{KX}\parallel\overline{OL}$. Similar reasoning shows that $\overline{LX}\parallel\overline{OK}$, so that $\square OKXL$ is a parallelogram.

Answer (score 0):

We may assume that $M$ is in the first quadrant with $AC$ vertical, $BD$ horizontal. Then there are angles $\phi$, $\psi$ with
$$A=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi), \quad C=(\cos\phi,-\sin\phi), \quad B=(\cos\psi,\sin\psi), \quad D=(-\cos\psi,\sin\psi)\ ,$$
and $$M=(\cos\phi,\sin\psi)\ .$$
It follows that 
$$K={1\over2}(\cos\phi+\cos\psi,\sin\phi+\sin\psi),\quad  L={1\over2}(\cos\phi-\cos\psi,-\sin\phi+\sin\psi)\ .$$
It is now easily checked that $\vec{OK}=\vec{LM}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For the reason of converse of angles in semi-circle, $u = v$ and similarly $x = y$

By angles in the same segment, $v = y$

Therefore, $x = y = u = v$

Also, somehow, $\theta = 90^0 – 2v$ and similarly $\phi = 90^0 – 2y$

Therefore $\theta = \phi$.

Will $\angle KML = 90^0 + 2u$?

If yes, the required result follows because KO // ML and also KM // OL (int. angles supp.)

Comment: What is converse of angles in semi-circle??